# How would you convert Binary field of type 4 to type 0?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How would you convert Binary field of type 4 to type 0 using Shell script ?

I thought about running simple script like this

```
db.places.find({}).forEach(function(data) {
    // How do I get to data ?
    print(data.id); 
    // db.places.update(....)
});
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get binary data so I can construct new Binary. `Object.keys()` shows there are only two fields: `type` and `len`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not force the type. I don't quite understand **why** you want to do this, but you can rewrite the document to force a new type:

```
db.places.insert( { id: new BinData( 0x04, "SEVMTE8=" ) } );
db.places.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5204c4f252d346a74dd17755"), "id" : BinData(4,"SEVMTE8=") }
```

So for your script, you can do this:

```
db.places.find({}).forEach(function(data) {
    bindata = data.id.base64();
    db.places.update( { _id: data._id }, { $set: { id : new BinData(0, bindata) } } );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to change type because `find` statement can't find documents that match data but has different type.